# Codeigniter blank page error

Tags: php, codeigniter-2

When I try to access the Admin panel in production environment I get a blank page. Well.. I tried to figure out what was going on and found something with some customizations that I've made in order to build the Admin Panel. There they are:

To autoload the libraries I used a function made by some TutsPlus instructor:

**config.php**

```
function __autoload($classname) {
    if (strpos($classname, 'CI_') !== 0) {
        $file = APPPATH . 'libraries/' . $classname . '.php';
        echo $file;
        if (file_exists($file) && is_file($file)) {
            @include_once($file);
        }
    }
}
```

Everything works perfect at development environment.. But it seems that the production app can't read my Admin_Controller (which is inside libraries folder and is extended from MY_Controller and give me this blank page.. Does anyone have an idea of what is giving this error?

Comment: Have you looked at your error logs?

Comment: When you are debugging, remove the error-suppression operator (@). The `include_once` line may produce useful output. For better results in general, you should use better error detection instead of error suppression.

Comment: The `@` in `include_once` will not show errors. So remove the `@` to see the error.

Comment: You might be running into a case sensitivity issue if you developed on a Windows environment but are running production on some *nix OS. Is your `Admin_Contoller` file name `Admin_Controller.php` or `admin_controller.php`?

Comment: I discovered something.. I've tried to output the classes from __autoload function and the result is http://test.com/admin:

CI_Hooks
CI_Config
CI_Utf8
CI_URI
CI_Router
CI_Output
CI_Security
CI_Input
CI_Lang
Admin_Controller
MY_Controller
CI_Exceptions

And from http://test.com/ is:

CI_Hooks
CI_Config
CI_Utf8
CI_URI
CI_Router
CI_Output
CI_Security
CI_Input
CI_Lang
CI_Loader
CI_DB
- - production database - - CI_DB

Comment: Wolf, you're absolutely right! The problem was related with the filname... In development mode it didn't crash 'cause it was running on a Mac OS, but the production server is Linux, so I got some problems over there.. I've solved following your instructions. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

i have same problem and also same tutsplus instructor. ive figured out in my localhost i was running a php ver. 5.5 and on the my hosting was running php ver. 5.3 after i had changed my php ver. 5.4 to 5.5 on the hosting it is now working. hope it helps you

Answer (score 0):

Go to **application/config/autoload.php** page and change

```
$autoload['helper'] = array();
```

to

```
$autoload['helper'] = array('url', 'html');
```